# Reaching an Object Outside of the Class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

I have started to learn Python recently and I am trying to make a basic GUI. I stucked at some point as you imagine. I found that code from the internet (possibly in stackoverflow) and am trying to modify it for the GUI which I want to make.

All code;

```
# imported necessary packages etc. 

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):  
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        # __init__ function for class Tk 
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.pack()
        container.pack_propagate(0)
        
        # initializing frames to an empty array 
        self.frames = {} 
        
        # iterating through a tuple consisting 
        # of the different page layouts 
        for F in (LoadPage, StartPage): 
            frame = F(container, self) 
            
            # initializing frame of that object from 
            # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with 
            # for loop 
            self.frames[F] = frame 

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")  
            
        self.show_frame(LoadPage)
        
    # to display the current frame passed as 
    # parameter 
    def show_frame(self, cont): 
        frame = self.frames[cont] 
        frame.tkraise()
        
def load():
    try:
        import data 
    except:
        print("Error...")
        
# first window frame loadpage 
class LoadPage(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 

        top_container = tk.Frame(self) 
        top_container.pack()
        top_container.pack_propagate(0)
        
        lbl_title = tk.Label(top_container, text = "TITLE")
        lbl_title.pack(side="bottom")
        lbl_title.pack_propagate(0)
        
        center_container = tk.Frame(self) 
        center_container.pack()
        center_container.pack_propagate(0)
        
        a_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"images/image.png"))
        image_area = tk.Label(center_container, image = a_image)
        image_area.image = a_image
        image_area.pack(side = "top", pady=50)
        image_area.pack_propagate(0)
        
        b_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"images/image.png"))
        btn_load = tk.Button(center_container, image = b_image, command=lambda:[load(), controller.show_frame(StartPage)])
        btn_load.image = b_image
        btn_load.pack(pady=10)
        btn_load.pack_propagate(0)
        
        lbl_load_inf = tk.Label(center_container, text = "INFO...")
        lbl_load_inf.pack(pady=5)
        lbl_load_inf.pack_propagate(0)
        
        bottom_container = tk.Frame(self) 
        bottom_container.pack()
        bottom_container.pack_propagate(0)
        
# second window frame startpage 
class StartPage(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        
        top_container = tk.Frame(self) 
        top_container.pack()
        top_container.pack_propagate(0)
        
        lbl_title = tk.Label(top_container, text = "TITLE")
        lbl_title.pack(side="top")
        lbl_title.pack_propagate(0)
        
        toolbar = tk.Frame(top_container) 
        toolbar.pack(side="bottom")
        toolbar.pack_propagate(0)
        
        btn_1 = tk.Button(toolbar, text ="BUTTON_1", \
                           command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        btn_1.place(relheight=1, width=220, relx=0)
        
        btn_2 = tk.Button(toolbar, text ="BUTTON_2", \
                           command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        btn_2.place(relheight=1, width=200, relx=0.18)
        
        
        center_container = tk.Frame(self) 
        center_container.pack()
        center_container.pack_propagate(0)
        
        figure = plt.Figure()
        ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
        chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, center_container)
        chart_type.get_tk_widget().place(relx = 0.10, rely = 0.3, relwidth = 0.6, relheight = 0.4)
        df["Column"].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind='barh', legend=True, ax=ax)
        ax.set_title('Title')
        
        bottom_container = tk.Frame(self) 
        bottom_container.pack()
        bottom_container.pack_propagate(0) 
        
# Driver Code 
app = tkinterApp() 
app.mainloop()
```

If you look at the StartPage class, there is a code block in init function;

```
figure = plt.Figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, center_container)
chart_type.get_tk_widget().place(relx = 0.10, rely = 0.3, relwidth = 0.6, relheight = 0.4)
df["Column"].value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind='barh', legend=True, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Title')
```

at this code block there is a DataFrame (df). It comes from data.py (imported via load function which triggered by a button in LoadPage). I said it comes from but I should have said it should come from. Unfortunately I could not get the data. DataFrame imported perfectly but somehow I cannot reach that df. How can I reach i? Possibly it is about class system but I cannot figure it out.

I got the error;

> NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Note: Code is a bit mess right now, I know. I will modify more in future. I am trying to learn how Tkinter, GUI, Python works just right now. Please pardon me for that messy code :)

Comment: Do some research on the difference between local variables (eg: `df` in your code) and instance variables (eg: `self.df`). Though, in this case the error is correctly telling you that you've never defined `df` anywhere.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  Well, I tried self.df too; not working. If I cannot figure it out why I am getting this error, I am going to change all the GUI structure unfortunately. It consumes my time.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  I will dig internet for some information. Thanks for the tip. Apparently I do not know the class system properly.